# How should I load a large NLP file into Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nlp, spacy, serverless

I have a NLP program which uses Spacy to load in a large word2vec file. This file is 3.75 GB and is too large to put directly in a lambda. Currently I have this program running in an extra large EC2 instance, but this option is expensive. The code also only runs on demand around four times a week, so keeping a server running constantly is not what I want.

- Is there any way I can convert this to serverless?
- If I use EFS, aren't I just converting one server to a server plus a lambda?
- Is there an API I can talk to which would return the same information that Spacy can, specifically similarity of two sentences?

Comment: Lambda can run for max 15 minutes and have very limited speed and ram as compared to extra large EC2 instance. Are you sure lambda would be enough? And yes, you would have to use EFS.

Comment: But does using efs give me anything? Wouldn't it just be swapping one expensive server for another?

Comment: lambda is not a server. EFS is only for persistent storage between lambda executions and to overcome 500 MB limit of lambda. But  is much cheaper then extra large EC2 instance. At the same time it has lots of limitations as compared to a regular instance.

Comment: So if I understand your comments correctly, given the large file lambda wouldn't be a good solution even with the model accessed through EFS. And you would simply recommend sticking with a large EC2 instance correct?

Comment: You can also consider using Docker and ecs, if you don't want ece i

Comment: You could also consider using Docker and ecs.

Comment: ECS is just a cluster of EC2 and Fargate instances, so that would have the same pricing problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219059/discussion-between-connor-oleary-and-marcin).